# Is there a way to get in SQL the column name and its values for the whole table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
col1   col2
-----------
val1   val2
```

and would like to get a string like

```
col1 = val1, col2 = val2
```

to insert everything in another environment.

I couldn't find an easy way so far to do this - I manage to get the column names and of course the values but how can I combine both?

```
SELECT s.name 
FROM sys.columns s 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('myTable')
```

Comment: SQL server tools include data import and export tool - this is maybe simpler than manually construct entire query.

Comment: You might also want to look into using XML. Without some sort of encoding how do you plan on handling unusual column names and unhelpful values, e.g. column `From Vogons` with the value `The Answer's Value = 42`?

Comment: Please explain what are you actually trying to do. Copy data elsewhere?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes I want to copy quickly rather small tables from one server to another.

Comment: @HABO i guess i can mask that somehow, but since the data is clean it shouldnt be an issue in the first place.

Comment: @Arvo Dont know this tool, if its possible to query this I would prefer

Comment: One of the quickest ways to copy small tables is to generate the insert statements (and optionally the table creation script). Then you can just copy it, paste it into the target server and run it. If it's a different database on the same server, there's an even easier way

Comment: About SSDT - look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/welcome-to-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `concat()`?

```
concat('col1 = ', val1, ', col2 = ', val2)
```

Comment: SELECT s.name FROM sys.columns s WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('myTable')  gives me all table col names, and SELECT col1, col2 FROM myTable all values. With Concat I understand how to combine manually defining col1= etc - but I would like to have a query giving me everything at once if possible without defining the cols on my own..